# Creating a simple toggle

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, flipflop

I have a signal that goes high at random intervals, and I would like to have each rising edge toggle an output. Something like this:

[image]

I've looked into flip-flops, but they all seem more complicated than what I'm looking for (I don't understand why most of them need a clock). Is a flip-flop the appropriate component to achieve these results? If so, which one?

Comment: http://hackaweek.com/hacks/?p=344

Comment: Interesting. I'm hoping to have this toggle millions of times a second–I wonder if having a capacitor charge will slow it down.

Comment: I think the capacitor on the circuit makes it slow down (to accommodate for the bouncing of the switch) so maybe if you remove/lower the value it would work

Comment: Absolutely, a flip-flop is the thing to use (though as what you need doesn't have to be clocked, some would call it a latch instead of a flip-flop).  As to which, D (for Delay), T (for toggle), JK, all will do the job.  I don't think you could accomplish the job more simply than with a T latch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A D flip-flop is the (or at least a) solution for this.  You would connect your input signal to the flip-flop's clock input, and the ~Q output of the flip-flop back to the D input.  There are also T flip-flops that effectively have the ~Q to D connection internally.

If the flip-flop you choose has Set and Clear (or Reset) inputs, they should be connected to whatever level will allow the flip-flop to operate (usually High, I think).